# Why is my description div ignoring the description-containers padding?

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper for my description which has 20px padding. Then I have a description div with to much content.

The wrapper container uses `overflow: hidden` so any content outside this container is hidden. But why is my description div ignoring its wrappers padding?

Is it because I'm using `box-sizing: border-box`?

See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nZ38w/2/

*update:* I can set the height of the description box and then use overflow: hidden, but isn't there another way? (http://jsfiddle.net/nZ38w/4/)

*Update 2:* It seems that setting a new height on the `details-right-section` is the only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nZ38w/5/

Code:

```
<div class="row">   
  <section class="column1"> 
      <!-- data here --> 
  </section>

  <section class="column2 details-right-section">
    <div class="description-container" >
      <h2>Description</h2>
        <div class="description">
          To much content here
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
</div>

/* CSS */

/* Rest css */
body { font-size: 12px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
h1, h2 { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div, section { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Main elements */
.row { width: 300px; height: 175px; }

.column2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: #cbdddc;
}

/* Description container */
.description-container {    
    height: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 1px #ff8182;
    padding: 20px;
}

.description {
    line-height: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

Comment: When you use overflow:hidden; it only hides what is outside the div. The padding is inside so it doesn't include that. You could manually change the height of the 'description' div.

Comment: Is the only way to set a different height? See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nZ38w/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another div `class="description-overflow"` and since you know the exact height would be `175px-40px` it would give you the output you wanted

http://jsfiddle.net/nZ38w/6/

Comment: Since there seems to be no other alternative, I'll go for this solution (without the extra div ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Try either removing the `height: inherit;` from `.column2`, or removing `height: 175px;` from `.row` (or changing `height` to `min-height`).

Comment: I can't remove the height of the row. I've tried a lot of things that doesn't work. You can test your suggestion with the fiddle.

Comment: Well, actually, in your first fiddle, jsfiddle.net/nZ38w/2/, it does work.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it works. In my full solution, the row div contains a lot of other elements and it is designed to be 175px in height. So I "can't" remove it.